# How do I know the arealearning has synced?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have some code in C# in Unity together with Project Tango that loads a specific AreaDescription from my Tango. Then I run the Startup command with the AreaDescription and it works all fine.

My problem is that depending on light during the day, the actual time it takes from loading the AreaDescription to getting synced where all the different models are in place can take anything from 1 second to 1 minute.

How do I know in programming code when it's synced without having to check if the models are in sync? I know about the OnTangoServiceConnected, but that is just when it gets connected, not when it recognised the room.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer elsewhere. Basically you can just look to see if the Tango Cameras location is changing.